# Bootstrap CSS - Always set card header to 2 lines height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a page (Angular) that dynamically displays bootstrap cards that looks as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card border-primary p-0 mb-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 colxs-12" *ngFor="let m of myVals">
        <h4 class="card-header text-center">{{m.Title}}</h4>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5>{{m.Year}}</h5>
            <img [src]="m.Poster" [alt]="m.Title" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is with the element `<h4 class="card-header text-center">{{m.Title}}</h4>`

The challenge is that sometimes the title gets displayed on 2 lines, other times on 1 (but never more than 2) and, so, the cards aren't looking uniform.

What I'm wondering is if there's a Bootstrap / CSS way to always make the `card-header` display as 2 lines high regardless of the text within it. I've tried setting a CSS style of `line-height: 2`, but it's not affecting it at all. Any correct / better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```css
<div>
  <h4>
    <span>One line heading</span>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <span>Assume this heading has two lines</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
h4 {
  height: 2.5em;
}

h4 span {
  line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom CSS to do it. check working fiddle below -

```css
.card-header-custom {
  min-height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-custom">Header big content Header big content </div>
        <div class="card-body">Content</div> 
        <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-header-custom">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">Content</div> 
        <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```